# HitTest trigger new scene

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

This is my code:

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){
    if(_root.char.hat.hitTest(this)){
        _root.gotoAndStop(6);
        _root.char._y +=50;
        _root.grav = 20;
    }
}
```

How to make the hitTest trigger new scene ?

Answer (score 0):

To go to another `scene`, you can use [`gotoAndPlay()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000389.html) or [`gotoAndStop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000389.html) :

> gotoAndPlay([scene:String], frame:Object) : Void.
>
> gotoAndStop([scene:String], frame:Object) : Void

So your code can be like this, for example :

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame)
{
    if(_root.char.hat.hitTest(this)){
        
        // ...
        
        gotoAndPlay("Scene 2", 1);
        
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: @AmirulSyahir I think that's just a scope problem ... try `gotoAndPlay("the_name_of_your_scene", 1);` ... or try to put your code in the main timeline action ...

Comment: When i tried to put the code in timeline ,the error pop out said clip events are permitted for movie clip instances.

Comment: @AmirulSyahir You can change the nested `onClipEvent(enterFrame){ /* ... */ }` by `your_mc.onEnterFrame = function(){ /* ... */ }` in the main timeline.

Comment: what is your_mc ?? @akmozo