# AS2 : HitTest to trigger new scene

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

i'm still stuck on moving to another scene

```
onClipEvent(enterframe){
if (this.hitTest(_root.char.hat))
  {
   gotoAndPlay("Scene 4",1);
  }
}
```

_root.char.hat is the character. So when the characters hit the object movie clip, it should go to new scene. any solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HitTest trigger new scene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737676/hittest-trigger-new-scene)

Comment: I answered your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33737676/2256820), there is no need to duplicate it here !

Comment: @akmozo Hello guys, i'm having a problem with vcam. Can i put button in vcam ? I'm using AS2 flash. I'm making a 2d game so exit button is a must in a game. Any help please